# Real device not showing in android studio

Tags: android, flutter

I have tried to connect my mobile phone to the computer to connect for android studio,
but there is no  any device appear in devices,
And the virtual devices with genymotion are appeared  with no problem,
I have activated Usb debugging mode and try to connect more than one device which working in other PCs ,
what can I do

Comment: there are loads of posts relating to this, i doubt you've tried all of them, have you tried using a different cable ?

Comment: You can follow [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device)

Comment: some android-device brands requires a device-driver on the pc side under ms-windows. What brand does your android-device  have? what os does your pc have?